# SQL Server - Joining Queries With Matching Values in Two Columns

Tags: sql-server

Pretty new to Sql Server and I'm looking to join two queries while matching two columns. E.g. If column TimeByDay & ResourceName in query Capacity match the Column TimeByDay and ResourceName in query Allocation then pull the values in Capacity. Any other recommendations are welcome. Please let me know if I'm unclear. Thanks.

QueryAllocation

```
ProjectName TaskName    ResourceName    ResourceManager AssignmentWork  TimeBYDay
Project1      Task1     ResourceA       ManagerA        8               2015-1-1
Project1      Task2     ResourceB       ManagerB        7.5             2015-1-2
Project2      Task3     ResourceA       ManagerA        4               2015-1-5
Project3      Task4     ResourceA       ManagerA        1               2015-1-5
Project3      Task5     ResourceB       ManagerB        2               2015-1-5
Project4      Task6     ResourceC       ManagerB        2               2015-1-5
```

Query

```
SELECT
  P.ProjectName,
  T.TaskName,
  R.ResourceName,
  RUV.[Resource Manager],
  ABD.AssignmentWork,
  TBD.TimeByDay

FROM dbo.MSP_TimeByDay TBD
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay ABD
  ON TBD.TimeByday = ABD.TimeByDay
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment A
  ON ABD.AssignmentUID = A.AssignmentUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource R
  ON A.ResourceUID = R.ResourceUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView RUV
  ON R.ResourceUID = RUV.ResourceUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmTask T
  ON A.TaskUID = T.TaskUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmProject P
  ON T.ProjectUID = P.ProjectUID

WHERE NOT (ABD.AssignmentUID IS NULL)
```

QueryCapacity

```
ResourceName    Capacity    TimeByDay
ResourceA       6           2015-1-1
ResourceB       4           2015-1-2
ResourceA       8           2015-1-5
ResourceB       7           2015-1-5
ResourceC       7.5         2015-1-5
```

Query

```
SELECT
  R2.ResourceName,
  RBD2.Capacity,
  TBD2.TimeByDay

FROM dbo.MSP_TimeByDay TBD2
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay RBD2
  ON TBD2.TimeByDay = RBD2.TimeByDay
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource R2
  ON RBD2.ResourceUID = R2.ResourceUID

WHERE NOT (RBD2.ResourceUID IS NULL)
```

Desired Results

```
ProjectName TaskName    ResourceName    ResourceManager AssignmentWork  TimeBYDay   Capacity    
Project1    Task1       ResourceA       ManagerA        8               2015-1-1    6
Project1    Task2       ResourceB       ManagerB        7.5             2015-1-2    4
Project2    Task3       ResourceA       ManagerA        4               2015-1-5    8
Project3    Task4       ResourceA       ManagerA        1               2015-1-5    8
Project3    Task5       ResourceB       ManagerB        2               2015-1-5    7
Project4    Task6       ResourceC       ManagerB        2               2015-1-5    7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks SimplyInk, I didn't know that the Query Designer could be opened in SSMS. I got the desired results now.

```
SELECT        
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID, dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentWork, dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay, 
dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.Capacity, dbo.MSP_EpmTask.TaskName, dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectName, dbo.MSP_EpmResource.ResourceName, 
dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.[Resource Manager], dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.[Resource Departments], 
dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.[Resource Role], dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceEarliestAvailableFrom, 
dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceLatestAvailableTo, dbo.MSP_TimeByDay.TimeMonthOfTheYear, dbo.MSP_TimeByDay.TimeDayOfTheMonth, 
dbo.MSP_TimeByDay.TimeYear

FROM            
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID = dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.ResourceUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay = dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.TimeByDay 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmTask ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmTask.ProjectUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.TaskUID = dbo.MSP_EpmTask.TaskUID AND dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmTask.ProjectUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TaskUID = dbo.MSP_EpmTask.TaskUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmProject ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectUID AND dbo.MSP_EpmTask.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmProject.ProjectUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceOwnerUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource.ResourceUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource.ResourceUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource.ResourceUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_TimeByDay ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay = dbo.MSP_TimeByDay.TimeByDay
```

I needed the following Join

```
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.ResourceUID AND 
dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay = dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay.TimeByDay
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the schema and relationships between your tables, so I'm taking a shot in the dark.

Please check if this query gives you the results in the format you need.

You'll will need to check that the join conditions do not create unnecessary duplicates due to the usage of [LEFT JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT
  P.ProjectName
  , T.TaskName
  , R.ResourceName
  , RUV.[Resource Manager]
  , ABD.AssignmentWork
  , TBD.TimeByDay
  , RBD.Capacity
FROM dbo.MSP_TimeByDay TBD
-- Query Allocation
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay ABD ON TBD.TimeByday = ABD.TimeByDay
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment A ON ABD.AssignmentUID = A.AssignmentUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource R ON A.ResourceUID = R.ResourceUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView RUV ON R.ResourceUID = RUV.ResourceUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmTask T ON A.TaskUID = T.TaskUID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmProject P ON T.ProjectUID = P.ProjectUID
-- Query Capacity
LEFT JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResourceByDay RBD ON TBD.TimeByDay = RBD.TimeByDay

WHERE NOT (ABD.AssignmentUID IS NULL) AND NOT (RBD.ResourceUID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi SimplyInk, I appreciate the help! I tried your query and it continued to run for more than five minutes so I stopped it. Retrieved about 20 Million rows while the Query Allocation creates about 900,00 rows. So you're probably right about creating duplicates since I'm using the LEFT JOIN. How else can I help you help me? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Paul, for tables with a 1:1 relationship you should be able to do a JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN to eliminate some unnecessary duplicates.

Comment: If you have access to MS SQL Server Management Studio you can visualize the relationship between table and data: Right click the dbo.MSP_TimeByDay table, Edit Top 200 rows, Click the "Show Diagram Pane (Ctrl + 1)" button on the Query Designer Toolbar. Click the "Add Table" button on the same toolbar to add the other tables one by one. Make sure to adjust the join condition before adding each table. (This is an interface to view and edit the table data, so be sure not to change the data or try this on a testing database!)